# unable to send email Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, actionmailer

i am new with ruby on rails mailer. i have created `Emailer` in `mailer` model.
my code looks like following.

my action mailer `Emailer.rb` is:

```
class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'saghir.alam@xxxxxxx.com'

def contact(recipient, subject, message, sent_at = Time.now)
      @subject = subject
      @recipients = recipient
      @from = 'saghir.alam@xxxxxxx.com'
      @sent_on = sent_at
      @body= message
      @headers = {}
   end
end
```

**emailer_controller.rb**

```
class EmailerController < ApplicationController
    def sendmail
      email = params["emailer"]
     recipient = email["recipient"]
     subject = email["subject"]
     message = email["message"]
      Emailer.contact(recipient, subject, message)
      return if request.xhr?
      render :text => 'Message sent successfully'
   end


      def index
      render :file => 'app\views\emailer\index.rhtml'
   end
end
```

index.rhtml file in `view/emailer` looks like this.

```
<h1>Send Email</h1>
<%= form_for :emailer,:url =>{ :action => :sendmail } do |f| %>
    <p><label for="email_subject">Subject</label>
        <%= f.text_field  'subject' %></p>
    <p><label for="email_recipient">Recipient</label>
        <%= f.text_field  'recipient' %></p>
    <p><label for="email_message">Message</label>
        <%= f.text_area  'message' %></p>
    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

here is my part of `routes.rb`

```
  match "/email", to: 'emailer#index'
    match "/emailer", to: 'emailer#sendmail'
```

my `config/enivronment/development.rb` is

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.server_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.xxxx.com",
   :port => 25,
   :domain => "xxxx.com",
   :authentication => :login,
   :user_name => "saghir.alam@xxxxxx.com",
   :password => "xxxxxxx",
}
```

my problem is when i click send button i can see "message sent" as it is shown in `emailer_controller`, but i hvn't have recived any. what is wrong with my code. plz guide me

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no error on rails server and rails log either

Comment: I can recommend the awesome [mailcatcher gem](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) for debugging email. With it, you can see if the mail is even sent, i.e. if the problem is in your app or e.g. with the SMTP server.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code that I think you should go READ Rails guides on that and then maybe ask questions. You have no idea what you're doing. Respective guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: But to point it out anyway. 1. Not even calling `mail` method in mailer. 2.  Not calling `deliver` on mailer. 3. Doing it all in development env where email are not sent by default.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel this is the link i have used for mailing http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm... btw thanks for pointing out problems with my code.

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri even looking at this tut there are errors in your code AND I think it's very deprecated I guess (Rails 2.0?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call 'deliver' like

```
Emailer.contact(recipient, subject, message).deliver
```

Comment: it didn't worked out, same issue. it says email sent, but i hvn't recieved it

Comment: What is your action_mailer configuration like?

Comment: Can you please tell me what version of Rails are you using?
Please refer to this for Rails 3
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration

Comment: i was missing the configuration of action mailer. i have fixed that, now i am getting `An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.` error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34511/discussion-between-saghir-a-khatri-and-hassan-javeed)

Comment: i was missing the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
 Emailer.contact(recipient, subject, message)
```

to
     Emailer.contact(recipient, subject, message).deliver

`Emailer.contact(recipient, subject, message)` will return a mail object. You have to call `deliver` on it to actually send it.

**EDIT**
Try changing settings to

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.xxxx.com",
  :port => 25,
  :domain => "xxxx.com",
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => "saghir.alam@xxxxxx.com",
  :password => "xxxxxxx",
}
```

Comment: it didn't worked out, same issue. it says email sent, but i hvn't recieved it

Comment: Login to this account `saghir.alam@xxxxxx.com` and check if the mail is present in sent items